# Grails: Quartz scheduler - setting the cron expression from db without restarting the program

Tags: grails, cron

```
Configuration config = Configuration.findByConfigurationKey("Scheduler")
    MyJob.schedule(config.configurationValue)
```

This is my code. It's working fine. But when I try to change the cron expression in db without re-running the program it won't work.
On every change of cron expression I have to re run.
Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the cron expression in the DB? You should be changing it through the Quartz API or it probably wont get picked up until you restart. Take a look at their docs. They are pretty good.